# Java Update Function

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine

Im currently trying to crate a countdown function in Java.

To start counting I was looking for an Update method like in Unity C#, where it calls script every frame which can then decrease the countdown value every frame.

Is there any function/method or any way to create a similar function in Java.

e.g.

```
float countdown = 30.0f;
Update() {
    countdown -= Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you're looking to use either a `java.util.Timer` or also the `ScheduledExecutorService`. Either could serve your need.

Comment: You should specify that you are developing a web application because I just guessed it.

Comment: `Time.deltaTime` is time that is need to finish `currentFrame`. If you write `Debug.Log(Time.deltaTime)` inside your `Update()` you will see that its value always changing.